# Accessing a class nested in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, nested

Is this possible, or should I find another pattern and forget nesting?

Any help much appreciated!

Gregzo

```
public class OuterClass<T> where T : InnerClass, new()
{
    public T GetInnerInstance()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
         public InnerClass
         {

         }
    }

}

public class Foo
{
    OuterClass<OuterClass.InnerClass> _instance; // nope
}
```

The goal is to let users extend InnerClass  and use OuterClass as a factory.

Edit: for clarity, here's the full pattern, completed thanks to Greg's help:

```
public class OuterClass< ProductType, ReturnInterfaceType > where ProductType : InnerClass, ReturnInterfaceType, new()
                                                            where ReturnInterfaceType : MinInterface
{                   
    private string _privateName;

    public OuterClass( string name )
    {
        _privateName = name;
    }

    public ReturnInterfaceType GetProduct()
    {
        ProductType product = new ProductType();

        product.SetParent( this );

        return new ProductType();
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        protected OuterClass< ProductType, ReturnInterfaceType > _parent;

        public InnerClass(){} //empty ctor for generic new()

        public void SetParent( OuterClass< ProductType, ReturnInterfaceType > parent )
        {
            _parent = parent;
        }

        //MinInterface implementation
        public string FactoryName
        {
            get{ return _parent._privateName; }//access parent private members
        }
    }
}

public interface MinInterface
{
    string FactoryName{ get; }
}

public interface MyProductInterface : MinInterface
{
    int productID{ get; }
}

public class MyProduct : OuterClass< MyProduct, MyProductInterface >.InnerClass, MyProductInterface
{
    public int productID{ get; private set; }
    static int __nbOfProducts = 0;

    public MyProduct()
    {
        productID = __nbOfProducts;
        __nbOfProducts++;
    }
}
```

Now it is easy to create a factory of whatever subproduct type and interface:

```
OuterClass<MyProduct, MyProductInterface> _factory;
_factory = new OuterClass<MyProduct, MyProductInterface>( "Factory");

MyProductInterface _protectedProduct = _factory.GetProduct();
string factoryName = _protectedProduct.FactoryName; 
//interaction with the outer class's private members is limited to the product's base class and minimum interface
//New members and interfaces can be easily derived
```

Comment: What language are you using, C#? Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify the language you're referring to. I assume it's C#.

The pattern you're using makes no sense, when you think about it. `OuterClass` itself is *not* a class; `OuterClass<T>` is a class.  In fact, the identifiers used for `OuterClass<T>` and `ΟuterClass` by the compiler are different, so you could actually define these two classes in the same file.

Because `ΟuterClass` itself is not a class, it obviously has no members. However, if you really wanted to, you could do something like this:

```
public class X : OuterClass<X>.InnerClass
{

}

public class OuterClass<T> where T : OuterClass<T>.InnerClass, new()
{
    public T GetInnerInstance()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        public InnerClass()
        {

        }
    }

}

public class Foo
{
    OuterClass<X> _instance; // yup
}
```

In order to parameterize `OuterClass`, you first need to create a type that matches the zany constraint you want. You cannot actually use `OuterClass<T>.InnerClass` because you first need a type `T` that matches the constraint `T : OuterClass<T>.InnerClass`. It sort of becomes a catch 22 type situation. You avoid it by explicitly defining the type.

Comment: Many thanks Greg, much appreciated. Why zany? I'm using this pattern so that all classes extending InnerClass can access OuterClass's private members. Users extending InnerClass do not need to know anything about it's base functionnalities, but can easily add new methods and use OuterClass as a factory. Maybe there are drawnacks I can't see yet?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your explanation, inheriting from a nested class doesn't give you access to the `private` or `protected` members of the nested class's container class.

However, if that's what you're after, you could have `ΙnnerClass` inherit from `OuterClass<T>`. That could give you access to the protected members.

Comment: Hi Greg, I've just added the full pattern to my post - easier to code than to explain. Super zany? Does the trick for my use case... Many thanks again for the help.